# Magento SOAP API: How to interact with it from fiddler?

Tags: magento

We are chasing something deep in Magento, and need to play with its SOAP entry point from fiddler. (We can call Magento SOAP fine from SOAP client code in php and .net, but we need to interact with Magento SOAP in a more interactive way. I mention fiddler here, but some other simple tool would be OK.)

We can successfully call : /index.php/api/v2_soap/index 
with header:
SOAPAction: "urn:Mage_Api_Model_Server_V2_HandlerAction"

and make a "login" call (passing in a username and apikey) and get a loginReturn just fine. (This is the session, we believe)

However, no matter what follow on request I do (, etc), I get this error:

5Session expired. Try to relogin.

How can I make this work from fiddler?

Comment: mind sharing what exact steps are taken in Fiddler?

Comment: You've confirmed that this works using a simple PHP script right? Just want to rule out anything having to do with writing the session files on the host server

Comment: @FrancisKim OP revised

Comment: You can try to increase the session lifetime from `System->Configuration->Magento Core Api->General Settings`. The default value is 3600 (1 hour), but it's possible that due to timezone settings and server time this to be viewed as expired every time. (moved as a comment at the request of OP)

Answer (score 1):

SOAP UI is a great tool for this. http://www.soapui.org/
(The free version is fine)

I have used this many times with the magento SOAP API V2 so can confirm it works well.

Here's a quick overview on how to get up and running.

1. Create a project and supply it the URL to your wsdl: 
   http://yourmagenotsite.com/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1

   This will add your project to the left hand pane. You can expand the tree to see a list of all available functions.
2. Find **login** in that tree, expand it and click **Request 1** to open it in the main window.
3. Enter your api username and password(APIKEY) into the XML, then click the green triangle in the top right to submit it.
4. The right hand pane will load the response. In that response should be your session ID. You will need this for all subsequent API requests, so copy it to the clipboard.
5. Choose another function from the tree on the left. E.g: salesOrderList. (expand it and choose Request 1).
6. Use that Session Id from your clipboard to populate the Session Id field in the SalesOrderList XML request.

Submit it and you should get an XML response of all Sales Orders.